# ASP.NET Core generate .well-know/jwks.json

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I have small web service (ASP.NET Core 3.1) which signs JWT, using RSA Private Key. I need to provide RSA Public Key as `https://myService.com/.well-known/jwks.json`

Is there any library which can provide JWT Web Keys in particular format?